# What are the steps to migrate a Magento Go site to Magento Community edition?

Tags: magento-community, migration, magento-go

Since Magento Go is closing, I need to move a site from Go to the Magento Community edition and would very much appreciate if someone could advise me on how to do this. I've tried Googling, but unfortunately most of the results are companies offering to do it for you (for a hefty sum). Essentially, I want the site to remain pretty much as it is now in terms of appearance - is this possible?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just in case, I think this is an important question and if it is too broad, we should give a roadmap, no detailed answer ;-)

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt : I know this question is important. That is why I told questioner to move question from stack overflow to here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565808/what-are-the-steps-to-migrate-a-magento-go-site-to-magento-community-edition . I am eagerly waiting for the answer :)

Comment: It's all very simple, you perform a clean install of CE, and use cart2cart to migrate transaction data. The rest is site specific such as theme and custom fuctionality - not that you actually need much if any. Usually best to do a clean product upload.

Answer (score 2):

We have also done this for several clients. It is quite easy to do, but does involve a lot of manual work.

Steps to follow:
- export products to csv file from Magento go
- export list of customers from Magento go
- work on these files to be able to import them into Magento community
- copy CSS files from go to community edition
- change themes and template of community edition to reflect design of Magento go
- change configuration settings in Magento community edition backend

As you see  a lot of manual labor, so therefore the companies charge a hefty sum. Unfortunately no automatic solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

If you are short of time and don't want the manual work, something like the below might be worth looking at.

https://www.nimbushosting.co.uk/blog/free-migration-from-magento-go-to-community-edition

We have our hosting with this company, we've used Magento Community from day 1, but stumbled over this offer a few weeks ago. If you are planning a server hosting upgrade in the near future, it might be worthwhile.

Failing this as Patrick mentions there is no quick fix/automated upgrade function. So manual job it is exporting customer and product data etc. Not complicated mind you, just fiddly.